# Unable to decode "devanagari text" passed as URL param

Tags: python-3.x, flask, character-encoding, flask-restful, urldecode

My Python Flask App is unable to decode the devanagari text eg:"सिंगापूर" that I pass as urlparam from my postman. If I sen english text it handles it well.

My PostMan query :
GET [http://localhost:5000/getSimilarWord/स](http://localhost:5000/getSimilarWord/%E0%A4%B8)िंगापूर

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

class DevnagriText(Resource):
    def get(self, textInput):
        print("parsed String is :",textInput)
        return {'text': textInput} 

api.add_resource(DevnagriText, '/getWord/<string:textInput>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The output I get on console is

```
{
    "text": "\u00818"
}
```

Instead of

```
{
    "text": "सिंगापूर"
}
```

Comment: This works for me running Flask-RESTful==0.3.6 and Flask==1.0.2. Perhaps your default encoding on your machine isn't utf8? What does it say if you print out `sys.getdefaultencoding()` before running the app?

Comment: I am also running Flask-RESTful==0.3.7 and Flask==1.0.2. It prints utf-8 on running that command. It didnt work for me though.

Comment: What happens if you go to that URL in your browser?maybe it's something with postman. Looks like they've had similar problems in the past. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2263

Comment: Ok when I ran in browser it returned me these value {"text":\u0938\u093f\u0902\u0917\u093e\u092a\u0942\u0930"} . Each of these such as "\u0938"  are Unicode escape sequences of Devanagari glyphs .
How do I get the original text "सिंगापूर" directly?

Comment: That should be fine though, no? If you read that into Python, it's equivalent, or you need it to actually render the characters in the response?

Comment: Yes I need actual rendered characters in the response

Comment: OK, in that case, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the response from forcing ASCII: `app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False`

So in your example:

```py
from flask import jsonify, Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
api = Api(app)

class DevnagriText(Resource):
    def get(self, textInput):
        print("parsed String is :",textInput)
        return jsonify(text=textInput)

api.add_resource(DevnagriText, '/getWord/<string:textInput>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But, this doesn't really matter, it will all get interpreted the same way if it gets read into Python or JavaScript.